# How to calculate sum in nested iteration in Struts2 tags

Tags: struts2, tags, ognl

Total spots is not printed in the span

```xml
<s:set var="totalSpots" value="0"/>
     <s:iterator var="spotSchedule" value="spotSchedules">
       <s:set var="totalSpots" value="#totalSpots + %{spotSchedule.noOfSpots}" />
     </s:iterator>
<span style='cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;padding-left:5px;color:blue;'>
   <s:property value="#totalSpots"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` sign to reference your `spotSchedule` variable inside `<s:iterator>` tag.

```xml
<s:set var="totalSpots" value="0"/>
  <s:iterator var="spotSchedule" value="spotSchedules">
    <s:set var="totalSpots" value="#totalSpots + #spotSchedule.noOfSpots" />
  </s:iterator>
<span style='cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;padding-left:5px;color:blue;'>
   <s:property value="#totalSpots"/>
</span>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote (and upvoted to counter it), but I'd suspect it's because (a) there's a particular user that tends to do malicious things like that, and (b) IMO the issue is more related to the use of the OGNL expression marker stuck in the middle of the overall OGNL expression.

Comment: And +1 to double counter :D Xxxx the haters